# Android WebView loadUrl JavaScript not working API <=18 (but works in API >=19)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

QUESTION:

What do I have to do to make webView.loadUrl(javaScript) work in API 18 or lower (in comparison to API 19 or higher)?

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM:

I am using WebView to make a chat.

1. First I load the HTML like so: **webView.loadUrl(url);**
2. Then I use loadUrl again to send in the chat message like so: **webView.loadUrl(javaScript);**

**This works perfectly fine in API >=19 but does not work in API <=18.**

Chat messages do still get received from other devices but the other devices do not get a single message from the device with API 18 or lower. ***The exact same code is used.***

I've searched a lot and will continue to search. If you have the answer, any idea that I could test or could redirect me to relevant information please do share. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

The JavaScript tag in the string is set to lower case (with the same problem): **webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + javaScriptFunction);**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**


I found the problem which was that the (encoded) message parameter sent in the JavaScript function had a line break [ **\n** ] in it. Removing that using the split function **msg.split("\n");** made it work.

Comment: Is that realy what helps you?

    `WebView wv = new WebView(mContext);` <br/>
    `WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();`<br/>
    `settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` <br/>
<br/>
    `JavaBridgeToJS bridgeToJS = new JavaBridgeToJS();`<br/>
    `wv.addJavascriptInterface(bridgeToJS, "javaCallback");`<br/>
    `wv.loadUrl("javascript: "var result=foo(); window.javaCallback.result(result)");`<br/>

while it's working just fine on API > 18, the callback is not called on 18 :( and there is no line break.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure this is what's causing your problem, but try using

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + theJavaScriptCode);
```

with lowercase `"javascript:"`.

API 19+ doesn't care about the case of the JavaScript protocol in `loadUrl` (though you can use `evaluateJavascript()` instead anyway in API 19+), but API 18 and down doesn't recognize it unless it's written in lower case.

Comment: I do have the "javascript:" tag in lower case so that's not it. Thank you though for sharing this information. Do you have any other suggestions? This really confuses me especially when I search for similar problems and find that people have problem making it work API >= 19 instead of API <= 18 as in my case.